# How to transfer bounded parameter using method super()

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have three classes: abstract A and two B and C which extends the A.

```
class A<T> {

   ArrayList<T> someField;

   A() {
      someField = new ArrayList<T>();
   }

   ArrayList<T> getSomeField() { return someField; }
}
```

Now I have B and C

```
class B<T> extends A {

   B() {
      super();
   }
}

class C<T> extends A{

   C() {
      super();
   }
}
```

When I try to use getSomeField which is different type for B and C I have to specify which type it is. And my question is how to transfer the T parameter from B class to A to avoid specify the type of ArrayList using for example for each loop. If it is possible at all.

Example:

I wish:

```
B obj = new B<T>();
for (T item: B.getSomeField) {
    do something
}
```

I have to:

```
B obj = new B<T>();
for (T item: (ArrayList<T>)B.getSomefield) {
    do something
}
```

Comment: I don't see `B` and `C` extending from `A`, neither class `A` is abstract.

Comment: Did you mean `class B<T> extends A<T>`? Otherwise you're extending the raw type. It would really help if you'd show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your `B` and `C` definitions, you are extending the raw form of class `A` and creating each class's own `T` generic type parameter.  The raw for of class `A` means that type erasure occurs on all generic in that class, and the casting becomes necessary.

You need to specify that your subclass's `T` is the same as the superclass's `T`:

```
class B<T> extends A<T> {
```

and

```
class C<T> extends A<T> {
```